# Notification pop-ups have changed colour and no volume pop-ups

Tags: sound, brightness, notification

Solved by reinstalling ubuntu.

I used to have the pop-ups showing up on the upper right corner which showed the next song playing and the volume and brightness while I adjusted it. After the most recent reboot they don't show up any more for volume and brightness and when they show up in other situations they are white with black text and the colour is no longer based on the background colour of my desktop.

[image: Error]

I am running ubuntu 16.04.4.

Does anybody know how to restore this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77821/discussion-on-question-by-kaasknak-notification-pop-ups-have-changed-colour-and).

Comment: That warning is a good sign that it already started the daemon, so you don't need to start it again. Did the semi-transparent popup with the claret red background not appear? Still old opaque popup? You can customize the popup via above mentioned `notifyconf` tool